# TCP traffic can't be routed from guest to host on Windows hosting Solaris 10 on Virtual PC

Tags: networking, dns, solaris, virtual-pc

I boot the machine and immediately issue a ping command to the VPC guest OS (Solaris 10). I use the **ping -t 10.3.6.63** (windows) command so that the ping continues on the windows machine.

This is what I get "Reply from 10.3.6.63: Destination host unreachable."

I log in to the solaris desktop and realize that my domain name was not resolved it is now at "unknown." I ping my host machine from the guest machine and immediately I get the pings to succeed on the host machine. If I continue to let the ping continue the connection remains stable and I can connect to some services on the guest machine from the host machine.

If I disable the ping service the connection will eventually die. My Oracle client will say connection refused for example.

I re issue the ping command notice that I get "Reply from 10.3.6.63: Destination host unreachable" again.

This time I cannot ping from the guest OS. So I run an **arp -d uspqlnb339** (domain name of host PC) and then re-issue the ping command from the guest OS; it succeeds and the pings start working.

What is causing this network path from being disrupted?

I run snoop on the guest account and I do see a lot of failure from the DNS server serving my host machine. For example

*"DNS R Error: 2(Server Fail) unkown -> uspqlsv131 DNS C `_`nfsv4idmapdomain Internet TXT ?"*

Perhaps this is a DNS issue. Is there any way to turn this off on Solaris 10?

Comment: How do you have configured the Solaris, static IP, DHCP? The VPC network on guest is doing NAT, Bridge?

Comment: I have it configured using DHCP (ipv4 enabled). The VPC is set to use the NIC in common with the host machine.

Comment: Not sure if this is still current but it sure sounds like ARP trouble. One way to kludge it might be to add a static ARP entry to the VPC on the (Windows) host. Something along the lines of either [Windows XP (TechNet)](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/arp.mspx?mfr=true) or [Windows Server 2003 (TechNet)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781485%28WS.10%29.aspx). But the actual problem seems to be somewhere else. Maybe check the MAC addresses of the host vs. the VPC (should differ) and/or check for duplicate IPs on the network, etc.?